# spring-boot, can i configure one externally accessible and one internal endpoint on the same port?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a service running in spring-boot with embedded tomcat.

Two different url endpoints on the **same port**, like

@RequestMapping("/endpointExternal")

@RequestMapping("/endpointInternal")

Only the first should be reachable on the external interface,
while the other should only be reachable from localhost.

Is that possible to configure somehow?

Comment: I think this can only be achieved by providing two separate Tomcat instances.

Comment: But is it then possible for two different spring-boot apps to listen on the same port? How?

Comment: Or do you mean two tomcat-instances on the same port in the same app? Is that possible?

Comment: Autowiring the request object will give you access to the remote address used. You could check for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910074/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java-httpservletrequest

Comment: You can use Spring Security to add that protection.

Comment: @M.Deinum --- Cool! I'll see if I can google that up.... :)

Comment: Something like `@PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('range-allowed-access')"` ont that method (or the URL if you want to block the URL already)....

Comment: Do you use physically separated network interfaces vor just separate IP ranges ? Is it your goal to increase security ? If yes then you should consider that IP addresses can be spoofed