# blacklisting a set of ipAdresses in a microservice created using java and SpringBoot framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration, blacklist

I have a micro-service designed to interrogate devices of different types and Operating Systems, but for a set of reasons , I want to blacklist a handful of IPs . Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: If you already have spring security write an expression that checks the IP-address. Basically an inverse check of what `hasIpAddress` does. You want a `notHasIpAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to check it in the [`HttpFirewall`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/firewall.html#page-title) which can check if a `HttpServletRequest` is potentially dangerous or not before allowing it to go through `FilterChainProxy`.

Basically you need to override the default `StrictHttpFirewall` and add the logic to check if the source IP of the request is in the blacklist , something likes:

```java
public class MyFirewall extends StrictHttpFirewall {

    private Set<String> backlistIPs;

    public MyFirewall(Set<String> backlistIPs){
         this.backlistIPs = backlistIPs;
    }

    @Override
    public FirewalledRequest getFirewalledRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws RequestRejectedException {
        
        String sourceIp = getClientIpAddress(request);

        if(backlistIPs.contains(sourceIp)){
          throw new RequestRejectedException("IP is blacklisted");
        }

        return super.getFirewalledRequest(request);
    }
}
```

<sub>*Note : Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910074/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java-httpservletrequest) for how to implement getClientIpAddress()*</sub>

Then configure to use it :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.httpFirewall(new MyFirewall(Set.of("123.123.123.123" ,"123.123.123.124"));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is again checking the ip of the request, which is not the case here.Is there a configurable property for blacklisting certain ips. I understand, we can do it through code mechanisms but , I am trying to crack a way if we can do it via configurations.

Comment: you must accept the fact the  client IP must  be checked from the HTTP request. If you do not believe it or willing to accept it , i think no one in this world can help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using HandlerInterceptor interface?

Combine with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.
This should do the job.

Something like this, not exact working code here

```
//Call after request processing, but before the view is rendered (after controller method call)
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    String ip = IPAddressUtil.getClientIpAddress(httpServletRequest);
    List<BlackList> blackLists = blackListDao.findByIp(ip);
    if (blackLists == null || blackLists.size() == 0){
        urlHandle(httpServletRequest, 5000, 10);
    } else {
         //Forced control jump
         modelAndView.setViewName("/errorpage/error.html");
    }
}
```

BlackListDao class can be something like this

```
@Mapper
public interface BlackListDao {
    //Find records by IP
    List<BlackList> findByIp(String IP);
    //Add record
    int addBlackList(@Param("blackList") BlackList blackList);
}
```

Configure the Interceptor Webmvcconfigureradapter for spring MVC.

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebAppConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean // inject our interceptor as bean
    public HandlerInterceptor getMyInterceptor(){
    return new URLInterceptor();
}
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    //Multiple interceptors form an interceptor chain
    //Addpathpatterns is used to add interception rules. Here we assume that all links after interception / URL
    //Excludepathpatterns user exclusion
registry.addInterceptor(getMyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/url/**");
            super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
```

Comment: My ask is about blacklisting the ipAddress of particular devices and not where the request came from ; Not sure , if an interceptor will help solve this problem ..!!

Comment: According to the tags he is using Spring security, thus it should be part of the security chain (that way everything is handled accordingly). @TimcyNihalani the ipaddress **is** where the request came from. How else would you check.

Comment: the request goes from one ip whereas the devices to be interrogated are different and have different ips. hence, cant rely on interceptors