SpringBoot get the request.remoteAddress() without org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerRequest
I am trying to get the request.remoteAddress() in a SpringBoot Controller class.
However, the controllers currently take the body as follow:

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @PostMapping("/coolendpointTWO")
    public String withRequestBody(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) {

        System.out.println("received object" + myPojo);
        //handle myPojo with my business logic

        String ip = ""; //How to get the IP, since I am not using ServerRequest
        return "good: " + ip;
    }

}

As you can see, the controller deals with the header and the body directly; it does not use the ServerRequest.
I understand this construct would allow to get request.remoteAddress().
@RestController
public class HelloServerRequestController {

    @PostMapping("/coolendpointONE")
    public String withServerRequest(ServerRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyPojo myPojo = request.body(MyPojo.class);
        System.out.println("received object" + myPojo);
        //handle myPojo with my business logic

        String ip = request.remoteAddress().map(InetSocketAddress::getAddress).map(InetAddress::getHostAddress).orElse("0");
        return "Message sent: " + ip;
    }

}

However, for other reasons, we cannot refactor (@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) -> (ServerRequest request). And actually, I would like to avoid having to take an entire ServerRequest in the method parameter just to get the remote address. The current construct (@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) is very helpful in understanding what will come as body.
Question:
While keeping the signature
    @PostMapping("/coolendpointTWO")
    public String withRequestBody(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) {

Is there a way to get the IP?

This should work (but will make unit testing a little harder).

if you are looking to get ip address from servlet, inject HttpServletRequest and call in request.getRemoteAddr() method.
and if you're using reverse proxy request, check out this answer's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910902/8733302
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @PostMapping("/coolendpointTWO")
    public String withRequestBody(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) {

        System.out.println("received object" + myPojo);
        //handle myPojo with my business logic

        String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        return "good: " + ip;
    }

}


@Autowire of the request doesn't look thread safe.

To Get access HttpServletRequest, you don't need to inject/autowire.
It's not an application bean.
Use as a method parameter, spring will automatically inject the current HttpServletRequest during the api access.
Like:
@PostMapping("/coolendpointTWO")
public String withRequestBody(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("received object" + myPojo);
    //handle myPojo with my business logic

    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    return "good: " + ip;
} 

You can also inject HttpServletResponse, Principal(from java.
